# Is there a way in windows to force/encourage a program to use a specific NIC (not as a developer)

Tags: windows, routing, network-adapter

I have multiple network cards, and can use more than one of them to connect to the internet.
It is simple to force connections to a specific target IP to go through a specific NIC, using the route command. But is there a way in Windows (7, 8, 8.1, or even 10) to force a program to open connections through one NIC, while still using the other NIC for all other programs, regardless of the target IP.

Built-in programs, power shell, sysinternals, anything that's official is fine.